# Change Username on Github

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

Previously, I change my **Github** account **username**. I create a new Repo and try to push something on it using git. But it returns error:

```
remote: Permission to <current-username>/<repo>.git denied to <previous-username>. 
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/<current-username>/<repo>.git/':
The requested URL returned error: 403
```

Anyone have a solution on this problem? Thanks

Comment: If you look closely at the error message, you'll see that your old credentials are still being used.  You probably need to cache your new credentials locally before doing any operations.

Comment: I already change the old credentials by changing the global and single repo username. I also change the SSH keys, but it still doesn't work. Do you have a solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should update your SSH key to or even the user name on your git local.

1. Update username and password

https://help.github.com/articles/setting-your-username-in-git/

2. Generate SSH key and add it to you github account.

https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/

Comment: I already do those thing, but the error message is same as I mention before. Do you have an alternate solution regarding this problem?

Comment: @MuhammadFauzanRazandi, try this on your repository: 
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/<current-username>/<repo>.git/
(Copy exactly link on your github and paste)

Comment: Thanks bro, already solved. It's working when I am using SSH.

Comment: That's great @MuhammadFauzanRazandi